Equivariant KR-theory of representation sphere
I would like to say my question first.
Let $G$ be a compact Lie group acting on a good space $X$ in a good way. Let $V$ be a $G$-representation whose real dimension may be less than 8, and let $S^V$ be the corresponding representation sphere. My question is: is there any way to compute the equivariant KR-theory $KR_{G}(S^V)$? And is there any relevant reference and any known examples of computing equivariant KR-theory?
The Bott periodicity for equivariant KR-theory seems more delicate than that for equivariant K-theory and that for KR-theory. The very reference for that is Theorem 6.3 in Atiyah's paper "Bott Periodicity and the index of elliptic operators". If the dimension of $V$ is 8, then we can reduce the computation of $KR_{G}(S^V)$ to that of the Real representation ring of the group $G$. But what about the dimension is, say, 4?
I have also read the series of paper by Chi-Kwong FOK on the computation of equivariant KR-theory of compact Lie groups. I'm not sure whether the idea there is helpful to the computation of $KR_{G}(S^V)$.
I think the computation of equivariant KR-theory of representation sphere may be easier than general cases, though I have no good idea how to start.

I read Atiyah's paper "Bott Periodicity and the index of elliptic operators" again. According to Theorem 5.1 in the paper, for any Real compact $G$-space $X$, and any Real $G$-module $V$, we can prove the isomorphism below analogously to that for complex K-theories.
$$ KR_G(X) \cong KR_G(V\times X).$$ This is also a Real verson of the Bott periodicity of equivariant K-theories.
For a Real representation $G$-sphere $S^V$, we have $S^V \cong S^0\wedge S^V$ where $S^0$ consists of the two fixed points, i.e. the south pole and the north pole. Thus, $$KR_G(S^V) \cong KR_G(S^0) \cong KR_G(pt) \oplus KR_G(pt) \cong RR(G)\oplus RR(G).$$
I really appreciate if you gives me any comments. Thanks.

I don't understand how to deduce from the first statement (about products) the second one. In the nonequivariant setting, we clearly have for any $X$ $H_m(X\times \mathbb{R}^n)\cong H_m(X)$, but $H_m(X\wedge S^m)$ and $H_m(X)$ might be rather different.
